# Mongoose count number of returned array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
User.find({job:"developer",sick:1},callback);
```

Above query gave me numbers of arrays object, but I just need the length of it. I tried `User.count({job:"developer",sick:1},callback);` it doesn't work.

I know I can use native **.length** native function but I want to use **count()** to optimize my query.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be something like this.

```
var query = {job:"developer",sick:1};
User.count(query, function(err, count) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(count);
});
```

The better way(depending on if you want to use the returned documents) is to use .length. However, if you are just doing this for speed then count is probably better.

To do it with .length:

```
User.find({job: 'developer'}, {sick: 1}, function(err, docs){
    var length = docs.length;
    console.log(length);
})
```

**The Difference**

.count() will only return the length without making a full query and loading the documents, while .length will take a returned array and get the length, which could take longer depending on what is being stored in your database

Comment: you should read Mongoose Doc (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) before making such statement.

Comment: I know your way will work, it is just not the best way to do it

Comment: Well your method wont work for the simple fact that mongoose async framework and your length would be null

Comment: what is the different using .length of javascript native function?

Comment: I would recommend using its native function just because it would allow you to work with the data and not just return the length. It would be slower but depending on what you want to do it may be better. I added some stuff to my answer to explain the difference

Comment: @Jasch1 wow really? Now what is the difference from your answer and mine?

Comment: @Rachel is this working? I tried it out and it worked for me

Comment: @Tim I had a typo in my answer(which I corrected) in which User was replaced with Song. Care to explain how that ended up in your answer which contains code which is word for word the same as mine?

Comment: @Rachel is any of this working for you? If not could you explain the error?

Comment: @Jasch1 I tried `User.count({job:"developer",sick:1},callback)` it doesn't return anything. Are you sure that will work?

Comment: It worked for me when I tried it. It's late where I live so I will look at it more and get back to you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Just use [count](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) function if you dont want to use .length

```
User.count({job:"developer",sick:1}, function(err, count) {
   console.log(count);
});
```

Some users (@Jasch1) recommend to use this:

```
Song.find({job: 'developer'}, {sick: 1}, function(err, docs){
    var length = docs.length;
    console.log(length);
})
```

However one thing to remember that .count returns number where .find actually returns actual data which could be very inefficient if you have big collection.

Comment: @Rachel ok does this work? User.find({job:"developer",sick:1},function(err, items){console.log(items)});